# What is this combinatorics problem involving polynomials?

Tags: combinatorics, analysis

I am trying to find when a certain descriptor for a polynomial equals zero.

Given a set of discrete complex points $B \subset \mathbb{C}$, a map $p(b):B \to \mathbb{N}$, and a set $A \subseteq B$ such that $\forall a \in A, p(a) = 1$.

I am asking when the following formula is equal to zero:

$$0 =\sum_{a \in A} \prod_{\substack{b \in B, \\ a \neq b}} (a - b)^{p(b)}$$

I am fairly certain of a couple of things. For example, if $B = A$ and $|B| > 1$, then the equation is zero, if $A = \emptyset$, it is also obviously zero. The answer cannot be zero if $|B| = 2$ and $|A| = 1$. I am thinking that the formula depends on the size of $A$, the size of $B$ and the values of $p(b) \mod 2$, which makes me believe this is a combinatorics problem.

It looks very fun if anyone wants a try, but I am feeling stumped for the moment.

Comment: You want $B$ (and therefore $A$) to be finite, right?

Comment: You say the expression is $0$ if $A = B$ but for $A = B = \{x, y, z\}$ I get $(x-y)(x-z) + (y-z)(y-x) + (z-x)(z-y) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xy - yz - zx$.

Comment: The problem statement needs clarification.  What does it mean for "a certain descriptor for a polynomial equals zero"? Are you trying to locate roots of a polynomial (a name for the sum of products would help to discuss this) or conditions for that polynomial to be identically zero?